# Дочерняя форма на месте родительской(с#)

Tags: c#

Создаю форму,но дочерняя появляется в другой стороне экрана, а хотелось бы на месте родительской.

```
reg f2 = new reg();
f2.Show();
```

Comment: winforms используете?

Comment: у формы есть событие появления обработайте его. берет координаты и размер и ширину той формы той надо и задаете той которой надо и все

Comment: Да,Winforms использую

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот что тебе надо это полностью перекроет окно родителя

выполнить при загрузке окна

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var parent = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form1>().FirstOrDefault();

            Height = parent.Height;
            Width = parent.Width;
            Left = parent.Left;
            Top = parent.Top;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

В настройках чайлд формы нужно выбрать CenterParent

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

создаешь инстанс формы, меняешь Size на нужный размер, а потом вызываешь метод Show() или ShowModal();

Comment: а если сдвину родителя в угол??

Comment: это влияет на момент создания формы. Не важно где родительская форма находится, хоть в углу на втором экране. Дочерняя форма появится по центру родительской.

Comment: Вот я и поставил CenterParent, даже сейчас одинаковый размер у этих двух форм сделал, но всё равно не на месте родителя.

Comment: @Andrew я про это и говорю

Comment: что имеется ввиду "не на месте родителя"? Ты хочешь что бы родительская форма закрылась? Или что не так?

Comment: Если у вас этот подход не работает, значит вы сделали что-то не так. Например, изменяли размер формы ПОСЛЕ того как форма показывается на экране, а не перед.